# Why does passing a method group to an overloaded method cause ambiguity when calling the method in a lambda does not in this case?

Tags: c#, lambda, overloading, method-group

Why can't the correct overload to be called be inferred on the line marked `// Compiler Error` in the code below when the type is correctly inferred in all the other cases?

```
public static class Code {

    private static void Main() {

        OverloadedMethod<string>(() => new Wrapper<string>()); // OK
        OverloadedMethod<string>(() => MethodReturningWrappedString()); // OK
        OverloadedMethod<string>((Func<Wrapper<string>>)MethodReturningWrappedString); // OK
        OverloadedMethod<string>(MethodReturningWrappedString); // Compiler Error

    }

    public static Wrapper<string> MethodReturningWrappedString() {
        return new Wrapper<string>();
    }

    public static void OverloadedMethod<T>(Func<Wrapper<T>> func) where T : class {
    }

    public static void OverloadedMethod<T>(Func<T> func) where T : class {
    }

    public struct Wrapper<T> where T : class {
    }

}
```

Here's the compiler error:

```
The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties:
'Namespace.Code.OverloadedMethod<string>(System.Func<Namespace.Code.Wrapper<string>>)'
and 'Namespace.Code.OverloadedMethod<string>(System.Func<string>)'
```

Answer (score 2):

Because the method group `MethodReturningWrappedString` can be converted to both a delegate of type `Func<Wrapper<T>>` and a delegate of type `Func<U>` for suitable values of `T` and `U`.

The overload resolution rules don't stipulate that the first conversion is strictly better than the second, so the conversion is ambiguous and results in a compiler error.

Comment: Does the lambda "() => MethodReturningWrappedString()" use different rules then?

Comment: So why is the generic constraint `where T : class` taken into account when a lambda is passed but not when the method group is passed?

Comment: But `Wrapper<T>` is a struct so it cannot satisfy `Func<U> where U : class`

Comment: @Craig: In that context there is no ambiguity for the call to `Method` -- there's only one overload, so that is selected.

Comment: @mikez: Good catch, but delegate conversion for method groups doesn't take that into account.